# How to toggle record in table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table `#temp` in SQL Server with the following records:

[image]

How to make only one true at one time and make other as false with just one query?

Comment: This question is not complete. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and run it multiple times ,so that it will make only one true at one time and make other as false

```
 DECLARE @COUNT INT 
 SELECT @COUNT=COUNT(1) FROM #tt

    SELECT id,custId,IsActive FROM
     (
    SELECT  id,custId, 0 As IsActive FROM #tt where id <=(@COUNT-1)
    UNION 
    SELECT  id,custId, 1 As IsActive FROM #tt where id =@COUNT
     )DT
    ORDER BY  NEWID()
```

if we run the query generates Result Randomly by giving 1 values as tru and others are false i.e 0

```
   id   custId  IsActive
  ----------------------------
    1       2       0
    2       2       0
    4       2       1
    3       2       0
```